# Angular production error: Property does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, get

I have an Angular 7 app that is retrieving data from two separate endpoints:

1. `http://localhost:1337/sms`
2. `http://localhost:1337/total`

I can successfully make a GET request to these endpoints in development. However, I get the following error when I run `ng build --prod`:

`ERROR in src/app/app.component.html(20,29): : Property 'total' does not exist on type 'object'.`

As a test I temporarily removed `{{ total.total }}` from app.component.html, ran `ng build --prod` again and it worked.

Is this not the right way to make GET requests to two separate endpoints or am I doing something else incorrectly, perhaps in my Node server file?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  signees: object;
  total: object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/sms').subscribe(
      data => {
      this.signees = data;
      }
    );

    this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/total').subscribe(
      data => {
      this.total = data;
      }
    );

  }
}
```

Relevant **app.component.html** code

```
<section class="page-section mx-auto">
    <h3 class="text-center">{{ total.total }} people have signed the petition</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"
      *ngFor="let signee of signees; index as i">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="h2">{{ signee.name }}</p>
            <ul class="signee-meta text-muted">
              <li>#{{ i + 1 }}</li>
              <li>{{ signee.date }}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->

  </section>
```

`/total` **endpoint (MongoDB)**

```
app.get('/total', (req, res) => {
    collection.countDocuments({}, function(err, num) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      res.send({total: num});
    });
  });
```

EDIT (added data structure)

**Data structure (MongoDB)**

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5c61e0b658261f10280b5b17"), 
  "name" : "Bill Kickok", 
  "number" : "+14950395584", 
  "date" : "2/11/19" 
}
```

Comment: What does `data` looks like?

Comment: @Ploppy It's the callback result from a Mongo call. I send it as an object. I added it at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown when you run `ng build --prod` because behind the scenes this kind of build proccess works with Ahead Of Time compilation.

Here's what happens on AOT based on [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

> Detect template errors earlier
>
> The AOT compiler detects and reports template binding errors during
>   the build step before users can see them.

You get that error because you try to render a property of total object while you have declared `total` as `object`.

In order to get rid of this error you should either create an `interface` for this variable. e.g.

```js
export interface Total {
   total: number
   // any other properties total might include
}
```

Then use this interface for type definition in your component like this:

```js
total: Total
```

In case you don't want to create an interface - **which is a bad practice** - you can define total as `any` (`total: any`).

Lastly, directly making the `http` requests in your component is also a **bad practice**. You should create a service, then add those `methods` which are responsible for communicating with your backend, then inject that service in your component and call that method.

I would advise you to take further look at [angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs).

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it would be a good idea to strongly type these properties, so instead of:

```
  signees: object;
  total: object;
```

If would be:

```
  signees: Signee[];
  total: Total;
```

Where `Signee` and `Total` would be interfaces:

```
export interface Signee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  date: string;
  // ...
}

export interface Total{
  id: number;
  total: number;
  // ...
}
```

NOTE: The above would match the JSON structure returned in `data` (which is why someone asked what the structure of your `data` looked like).

And if total is just a single number you are receiving back, then it would just be:

```
total: number;
```

And you would just bind to `total`, not `total.total`.

You can then use this strong typing when you send the request to ensure that the response is appropriately shaped:

```
this.http.get<Signee[]>('http://localhost:1337/sms').subscribe(
  data => {
  this.signees = data;
  }
);
```

Notice the generic parameter specified in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

you need start your object inside of constructor.

ex:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    total = new Total();
}
```

Total is your class. This is recomendate in angular.io. Start your VAR inside constructor.